# Pig takes long time to stroe into Hbase

Tags: hbase, apache-pig

Hi I am a new guy to hadoop.

Recently, I put a large amount of text files into HDFS.
What I wanna do is to read these files and put them into HBase using Pig (LOAD, STORE).
However, I found it takes long long time to store into HBase.

Does anyone meet similar situations before? If YES, how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I face the same issue when I use HBaseStorage. Actualy HbaseStorage does sequential PUT operations to load data into HBase. Its not really a bulk load. see this unresolved Jira.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2921

But I get significant performance difference after using **ImportTSV** option.
http://hbase.apache.org/book/ops_mgt.html#importtsv

The bulk load involved three steps
*1. Pig : Read data from source , format in HBASE table structure, load to hdfs.
2. ImportTsv : preparing StoreFiles to be loaded via the completebulkload.
3. completebulkload : move generated StoreFiles into an HBase table. (It's like cut-pest)*

Hope this is useful :)

Answer (score 0):

The time taken depends on the number of nodes you have and obviously the size of the file.
I think its better to check the number of nodes/dfs size w.r.t your input data set.

Comment: In my case, there are three datanodes, and each file is around 15 MB. I try to look at HBaseStorage.java, and find that Pig uses put to store data into HBase. Are there any solutions to speed up this part of action?